# how to use **GridLayout** for populating the data dynamically

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am working on a project where i have to use *GridView* to bind images from database. Here I have to set the number of Rows = 2 but column will be filled dynamically. So I researched and found that we can set number of rows and columns in **GridLayout**.

So I started working with this, But while working I got to know that there is no option like "android:layout_column= "auto_fit" . So, how can I get this as I dont know that how much data is going to be filled in columns??

Comment: GridView has numColumns property (`android:numColumns="auto_fit"`). 
Check this example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: @mata Yeah that i know, But we dont have any property like (android:numRow="?") in gridView.. That is why I moved to GridLayout. and this question is about Filling columns of GridLayout Dynamically.

Comment: You can set number of columns dynamically with `setNumColumns(int)`.   Divide number of images by 2 and set it as number of columns.